# No JIT Debugger has been specified when launching application

Tags: vb.net, debugging, compilation, jit

Hey,
I have a vb.net application that I compiled and all, 
I took the EXe and all and placed it on another pc that has only visual studio express on it.

When I open my .exe I get a message saying No debugger has been found,
no Jit Debugger has been specified
I can either select retry to find a debugger or click on cancel to forget about the debugger.

If I press cancel, my application launches correctly without any problem.

Any idea why this message appears? Can it be an error in the code? or could I be compiling wrong

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, unusual.  Is there a Debugger.Launch() statement in your code?

Comment: I do have a Debugger.Launch() and a #if Debug, should I remove them?

Comment: Well, score one for psychic debugging.  Yes, remove it.  Or run the Release build, a VB.NET Debug build leaks if you run it without a debugger.

Comment: Awesome!!! I removed the debugger.launch and the error message stopped appearing =D Thank you very much!!